# Data not fetched by angularjs app on deployment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, web-deployment, factory

I'm developing the angularjs app in local server i.e localhost. And I've shared the link of the project with my current IP address in my network, so that i could get feed-backs from my colleagues. But the page displays with no data  at all. But it displays all correct in my computer.

Am I missing the appropriate procedures or configurations? Could anybody guide me with link(s) on how should it be done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: i do not know where it went wrong. Which part of the code will be most appropriate to share..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks i will go through it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is working for you, I'd think that you bound your data on `localhost` or even `127.0.0.1`, this won't work for any of your colleagues, as they don't have the backend / data on their machine.

Bind your data using your IP, and if I'm not mistaken, that should solve your problem. If you bind your data to your IP, use a constant. That'll make your life easier when you actually deploy.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .constant('SERVER', '192.168.0.101/api/');

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', ['SERVER', '$resource', function(SERVER, $resource) {
        var mv = this;
        var data = $resource(SERVER + 'resource')

        mv.server = SERVER;
        mv.data = data.get();
    }]);
```

Comment: I have made the configurations as you told but no luck! thanks though!